# flymake error: no build file found, flymake switching off

Tags: emacs24, flymake

When I try to use flymake on a simple java program it immediately tells me that it is switching off because it cant find a build file. I thought that flymake would make all of the files it needed to execute on its own and that all that was required for Emacs 24 was to put (require 'flymake) and (add-hook 'find-file-hook 'flymake-find-file-hook) in the .emacs file.

I am using the flymake that came with Emacs 24 on Ubuntu 14.04.

This is my first post so please tell me what I can do to improve my questions! Thank you for your time!

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Apparently it's looking for a Makefile, which probably used to be common for java projects but aren't used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use flycheck instead of flymake, along with the flymake-java package found on github.